# Shader&Material system in OpenGL like in Unity

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I need to create Shader&Material system to just store shader uniforms and then set it up on render automatically. So I need:

1. Global properties: can be set for all materials and shaders (like u_CamPosition).
2. Shader properties: can be set for a specific shader. Those properties will be applied to every material of the shader.
3. Material properties: can be set only for specific material.

The main problem is... how? How I need to do this? What is the most efficient solution?

I had an idea to create a map for every type of value (floats, textures, Vector3, Matrix4).
But then I have to iterate over each material, shader and global property map in a render loop. Many of the properties will remain unchanged and a lot of unnecessary glUniform* calls can make rendering performance really bad.
So it's a good idea to keep track of what properties have been changed, **but how?** Is this extra check of what properties have been changed really worth it and doesn't make performance even worse?

Comment: When you change a property, can you enqueue the change into a queue that gets emptied when rendering?

Comment: @new QOpenGLWidget thanks for the idea.